# Date specific conditional

Tags: conditional

Hi I'm trying to template out a simple conditional that shows content if the date set in a date field is greater or equal to today, and I can't seem to get the syntax quite right.

I have tried this:

```
{% if entry.promoEndDate|date ('>= ' ~ now) %}
    <p class="price--notes">Price valid until {{ entry.promoEndDate | date('d M Y') }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

And this:

```
{% if entry.promoEndDate | date >= now | date %}
    <p class="price--notes">Price valid until {{ entry.promoEndDate | date('d M Y') }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Both don't yield the result I'm looking for.
Probably missing something really simple here but looked at it too long now.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just compare the two dates directly.

```
{% if entry.promoEndDate >= now %}
    <p class="price--notes">Price valid until {{ entry.promoEndDate|date('d M Y') }}</p>
{% endif %}
```